# Rename jQuery UI tab with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have 3 tabs :

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1"></div>
    <div id="tabs-2"></div>
    <div id="tabs-3"></div>
</div>
```

with this jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var $tabs = $("#tabs").tabs({
            select: function (e, ui) {
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I'd like when I do some operation on the first and the third tab, the label of second tab change the name from "Tab2" to "Other text"

I tried several way found on Google but any work.

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just run the following code and it will change the text for the second tab link.

```
$('#tabs ul:first li:eq(1) a').text("Other text");
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/3RpC8/) (click button in 3rd tab)

Comment: Thanks for your effort and for the example :)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, for anyone that wants to change the text of a **specific** tab, "#tabs-2" in this case:

```
$('#tabs [aria-controls=tabs-2] a span').text("New Label")
```

Note that this is dependent on the current formatting of the jquery-ui tabs and may need to be tweaked if the template changes in future versions.

Answer (score 2):

I found another solution if you don't want to use the indices in case they are dynamic.

```
$('#tabs a[href=#idoftab]').text("New Title");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#tabs ul li:nth-child(2) a').text('Other text');
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested in changing the text of the **selected tab**:

`$('#tabs .ui-tabs-selected a').text("New Title");`

Comment: or $("#tabs ul li[aria-expanded='true'] a").text("new tab title");