# How to rename currently selected tab using its tabIndex in kendo UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I need to rename a currently selected tab in kendo tabstrip. I only have have the index of the tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$($("#tabstrip").data("kendoTabStrip").items()[index]).children()[0].innerText = "New Title";
```

Or this:

```
$('#tabs [aria-controls=tabs-INDEX] a span').text("New Title");
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170517/rename-jquery-ui-tab-with-jquery)

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

you can use an event like activate

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/tabstrip#events-activate

and write a custom logic inside

```
     var onActivate = function(e) {
            // access the activated item via e.item (Element)
            if($(e.item).index() == 1)
            {
              $(e.item).text("Current tab 1")
              // detach activate event handler via unbind()
            };
            tabStrip.unbind("activate", onActivate);
          }
```